# Why is there no electric field in the Hamiltonian for the quantum Hall effect?

Tags: condensed-matter

I was looking at the [quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Hall_effect) and have a question:

The Hamiltonian we use has no electric field in it, but we say there is an electric field along the $y$-axis. Why are we not including this in the Hamiltonian or the Schrödinger equation? Furthermore, if there is a current, there must be an electric field - why aren't we including this either?

Comment: WHY ARE WE SHOUTING?

Comment: I guess your caps lock was on.....

Comment: yeah...sorry for that...i havenot thought of it...

Comment: Please note that you should not type in ALL CAPS. Also, three dots "..." are *not* a substitute for proper punctuation. Furthermore, you should *give the Hamiltonian you are talking about in the question* to make it more self-contained.

Comment: sorry...am new...i wont use caps unnecessarily hereafter...and thanks rene....

Comment: H=[(p+eA)2]/2m this is the Hamiltonian I was talking about. This Hamiltonian is for an electron moving in constant magnetic field. But when it comes to quantum Hall effect, we are telling there is an electric field along y axis. Why are we not including it in this hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

There is an electric field when you measure the Hall conductance. The electric field is not essential for the formation of the quantum Hall state itself: it is just a probe, and the Hall conductance is determined by the state and its low-energy excitations (via linear response theory, for example).